# use of Jdbctemplate in spring boot application for AWS Dynamodb

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I am building a spring boot microservices pointing to AWS dynamodb for database operation. I am using below library to interact: As such operations are working fine with CrudRepository, but it is very slow for mass operation. Do we any option like jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate() for dynamodb?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Dynamodb doesn't have batch update feature. It has to be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

The `batchSave` available on `spring-data-dynamodb` uses AWS SDK DynamoDBMapper batchSave which doesn't update the existing item.

DynamoDBMapper.batchSave internally calls AmazonDynamoDB.batchWriteItem() which doesn't support updating the existing item.

**DynamoDBMapper batchSave:-**

> Saves the objects given using one or more calls to the
>   AmazonDynamoDB.batchWriteItem(BatchWriteItemRequest) API. No version
>   checks are performed, as required by the API.
>
> This method ignores any SaveBehavior set on the mapper, and always
>   behaves as if SaveBehavior.CLOBBER was specified, as the
>   AmazonDynamoDB.batchWriteItem() request does not support updating
>   existing items.